# Package is currently froze when I try to autoupdate app - Android

Tags: android

i'm trying to create a auto-update application using a BroadcastReceiver to control the status instalation:

Everything works fine. But I want to reopen the updated app.

When I try to do that I get the following error:

```
Failure starting process com.artech.logitrans16.logitransapp
    java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.artech.logitrans16.logitransapp is currently frozen!
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.checkPackageStartable(PackageManagerService.java:4057)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:4263)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:4228)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:4210)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:4096)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startSpecificActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1730)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityInnerLocked(ActivityStack.java:2804)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityUncheckedLocked(ActivityStack.java:2319)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeFocusedStackTopActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2249)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeFocusedStackTopActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2233)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppDiedLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6000)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.removeProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:7586)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.killPackageProcessesLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:7223)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.forceStopPackageLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:7360)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$MainHandler.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:2318)
```

This is the BroadcastReceiver part code:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            //aca manejo el estado de la instalación
            String action = intent.getAction();
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + File.separator + "APP_GSOFT");

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            String errores = extras.getString(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS_MESSAGE);

            if (ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                int result = intent.getIntExtra(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS,
                        PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE);
                switch (result) {
                    case PackageInstaller.STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION:
                        startActivity((Intent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT));
                        break;
                    //Si se instaló correcto, reinicio la app con el nombre del packge
                    case PackageInstaller.STATUS_SUCCESS:
                        PackageManager s;
                        s = getPackageManager();
                        Intent launchhhh;
                        launchhhh = s.getLaunchIntentForPackage(nombrePackage);
                        int mPendingIntentId = 123456;

                        PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, mPendingIntentId, launchhhh, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, mPendingIntent);
                        UpdateApp.this.finishAndRemoveTask();
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_ABORTED:                       
                        borrarRecursivo(f);
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Cancelado por el usuario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        System.out.println("Cancelado por el usuario!");

                        UpdateApp.this.finish();
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    //En cualquier otra situacion, borro el APK
                    default:
                        borrarRecursivo(f);
                        System.out.println("Errores: "+errores);
                        UpdateApp.this.finish();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

I'm trying AlarmManager to reopen the app after 10 seconds

And i tried to use `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` Flag too but I got the same error.

All I want is to reopen the app.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and want to restart my app after auto update.

Found a solution:

Assuming you are using PackageManager to install your own app.
You can use PackageManager to fire any intent you want after updating the app.
So before commit the session, i do the following:

```java
Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("my.package.name");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
session.commit(pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
```

Just replace `my.package.name` with your packagename.
With this it's get restarted after the update.